# load cvs file in matrix python

Tags: python, csv, matrix

I have a CSV file that contains both string values and numbers. I need to load the values in a matrix and after that to start making changes on the values.

I am new to python and I couldn't figure it out. How can I load the values in a  matrix?

Comment: What's the format of your CSV file?

Comment: Please be more specific. Can you give us an example of the data and the kinds of changes you want to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csv.reader.next() will put the contents of the next row into a list.  If you call this as many times as there are rows in your file, then the reader object is a list of lists.  You can then generate another list of lists, but this time representing each *column* using the zip function:

```
columns = zip(*rows)
```

where rows is the name of the csv.reader object, which you called with

```
rows = csv.reader(YourFile, dialect='excel')
```

perhaps.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) allows you to easily read CSV records one at a time, and handles a few different "flavors" of CSV formatting (e.g., should whitespace at the front of each line be ignored, what character is used to quote values that contain the field separator, etc).

You probably want to put all the rows into an array, so you can change the values as necessary.